# How to create a Searchable Dropdown in TextFormField in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dropdownbutton, flutter-textformfield

I am new in flutter, I want to create a searchable dropdown in Textformfield in flutter. Like below-

I want to show icons in left side and text to the right as shown in image. When i click on any suggest item it should be go inside textformfield. Data will be loaded from server. I will receive icons and text in json format from server api call. Please provide me any solution to achieve that.

[image]

```
 Container(
              child: SearchableDropdown(
                value: _bankChoose,
                isCaseSensitiveSearch: true,
                items: bankDataList != null
                    ? bankDataList.map<
                    DropdownMenuItem<
                        BankListDataModel>>(
                        (BankListDataModel value) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: value,
                        child: Row(
                          // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            new CircleAvatar(
                              backgroundImage:
                              new NetworkImage(
                                  value.bank_logo),
                              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                              radius: 12,
                            ),
                            // Icon(valueItem.bank_logo),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 15,
                            ),
                            Text(value.bank_name, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontFamily: "verdana_regular",
                                color: text_gray_color, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    }).toList()
                    : null,

                isExpanded: true,
                hint: "Select one",
                searchHint: "Select one",
                onChanged: (BankListDataModel newSelectedBank) {
                  setState(() {
                    _onDropDownItemSelected(newSelectedBank);
                    print("selected Bank name " + _bankChoose.bank_name);
                  });
                },

              ),
            ),
```

Comment: check this on pub https://pub.dev/packages/simple_autocomplete_formfield

Comment: What is the problem you're facing? have you tried to implement this? it should be quite straight forward with a Dialog, ListView and TextField.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh, simple_autocomplete_formfield working fine. When when i press in textformfield the suggestion list create space , so the next formfield dragged below. It should be like dialog box. How to do that?

Comment: check this https://github.com/yeasin50/BasicBankSystem/blob/dcbd65956b7fc390f49e5e5365738b31cf3cc4df/lib/screens/moneyTransferScreen.dart#L94-L131

Answer (score 0):

you can use this package to achieve what you are trying to do
[enter link description here](https://pub.dev/packages/searchable_dropdown)

Comment: I used this one, but suggestions are blank, I don't know why?

Comment: so you want the suggestion to be like the uploaded

Comment: In simple way, suggestions are not showing when i am searching something.

Comment: post the code of the plugin you use. i mean the plugin code i said you use but not showing suggestion

Comment: okay.. i will create a fresh project and paste the code

Comment: Hi, Are you creating the code which you want to show?